# Generate multiple log files from same output.xml file in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have an output.xml file containing all the testcases I have ran. I am trying to generate a separate html log file for each testcase. For that, I am calling rebot from python for each testcase. However, rebot is parsing the output file each time which is taking a lot of time.

Is there a more efficient way to do it in python using robot built-in libraries?

Comment: Without knowing more on what you have tried and what you need it's impossible to provide a proper answer. But you could use a [listener](https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/extending_robot_framework/listeners_prerun_api/listeners#report-listener) to write the report after each test case ends with the data you need.